# Is there an R function for displaying multiple x axis labels and y axis labels?

Tags: r, plot

Image: plotted the relationship between 4 variables, resulting in 12 scatterplots

[image]

In the image above, I've got 12 scatterplots, but no axis labels making it a bit difficult to know what each scatterplot is showing.
I believe I can just use the xlab and ylab function to tell R what the axis labels should be if I only have 1 scatterplot. But if I have 12 scatterplots, is it possible to tell R to somehow use the appropriate heading from my csv file as the x-axis label and y-axis label for each plot?

Here is a screenshot of my data if it helps:

cheese csv screenshot

[image]

Comment: for each plot just look up or down for the x-variable and left or right for the y-variable. by the way this type of plot is documented in `?pairs`

Comment: Hi @rawr! Apologies, I'm a novice in statistics and R so I'm not 100% sure how to read my output. I was hoping you can elaborate on what you mean if that's okay?

Comment: Hi @rawr! Apologies I'm a beginner with R... Am I correct to assume that for the 1st plot (to the right of 'taste'), it's showing taste on the y-axis and acetic on the x-axis?

Comment: That's correct. And the plot 2 to the right of "taste" shows taste on the y axis and H2s on the x-axis. If you use `ggExtra::ggpairs(your_data)`, you might like the output a bit better: the labels are clearer and there's a bit more information.

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, thank you for helping clarify that for me, and I'll try that!

Comment: @GregorThomas is that from `GGally`? and when did significance stars come back in style

Comment: rawr is right - `GGally::ggpairs`, not `ggExtra::ggpairs`. I hope the significance stars are easily disabled ;)